# Compare object with objects

Tags: javascript, object, compare

I have that object with simple objects

```
public positions = {
    reading: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    writing: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    speaking: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    listening: {
        left: "0px",
    },
};
```

I need to check if some of the 'left' properties are the same and if they are add 'top' property to one of them. For example if I have object like this:

```
public positions = {
    reading: {
        left: "10px",
    },
    writing: {
        left: "20px",
    },
    speaking: {
        left: "20px",
    },
    listening: {
        left: "7px",
    },
};
```

Sholud be transformed to this:

```
public positions = {
    reading: {
        left: "10px",
    },
    writing: {
        left: "20px",
    },
    speaking: {
        left: "20px",
        top: "10px"

    },
    listening: {
        left: "7px",
    },
};
```

I need simplest way to do that.

Comment: `public` ? what language is this - so you want to add `top: "10px"` to `positions.speaking`? ... like: `positions.speaking.top = '10px'`

Comment: Have you defined the priorities? Which should come first?

Comment: What if there are multiple such keys with same value? should the `top` value be always `10px`? Is `left` the only property a position can have? What if there are multiple common properties?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
const positions = {
    reading: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    writing: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    speaking: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    listening: {
        left: "0px",
    },
};

const positions2 = {
    reading: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    writing: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    speaking: {
        left: "0px",
    },
    listening: {
        left: "0px",
    },
};

for (var key in positions) {
  if (positions2[key].left == positions[key].left) {
    positions2[key].top = '10px'
  }
}

console.log(positions2)
```